# Property mediator is disappearing in WSO2 EI 6.6

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm trying to send the token before the endpoint but it's disappearing when it's deployed in the server and I even try to the pass the token within the endpoint properties but it's not accepting and thrown error like Invalid token, please help me to sort this out.

```
                        <log level="custom">
                        <property name="uri.var.apiurl :::::::::::::::::::   " expression="$ctx:uri.var.apiurl"/>
                        <property name="Authorization :::::::::::::::::::   " expression="$trp:Authorization"/>
                        </log>                            
                        <call description="VB iAppraisal Endpoint">
                        <property name="Authorization" scope="transport" value="Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjllMDA1MGQ4ZDFlNmZlMTYzMjllMGViYTY1MmE4NDBhMTZhMDUzZjQ3MWU0OTA4MmE0Y2ZkOGI2NTZhYjU3N2NkMmEwNTUxNjhkYzVhMjRiIn0.eyJhdWQiOiI3MjUiLCJqdGkiOiI5ZTAwNTBkOGQxZTZmZTE2MzI5ZTBlYmE2NTJhODQwYTE2YTA1M2Y0NzFlNDkwODJhNGNmZDhiNjU2YWI1NzdjZDJhMDU1MTY4ZGM1YTI0YiIsImlhdCI6MTY1MDk2ODgzMiwibmJmIjoxNjUwOTY4ODMyLCJleHAiOjE2ODI1MDQ4MzIsInN1YiI6IjU3NCIsInNjb3BlcyI6W119.BUyx65owuErEmx57_N-FC4kT_QvPQ01pvof_308hjWHPbfrajajs2oGJx0hTuztQUT5xTKqMEV9pFHfdUKM93VWTBBCMFrbP9Qg03dq1Se9fbXGJ5EkmRiAy9qJ2WCiMs2sj6sN3H7_aWxn0D6u9kbfymzRUdw3pP9KT0L0hl03RRAliW0JpVv6qJgog2bvCJni_BsM5kt84dXFohbEtRqas40bYCd-VHqy-pxlVbq6-y27OF5XC-qcWRxT78iXG2P9joULCZKTHINUPigpT2h8-QA8nPakmDflEgLScG1yAKlcgDY1aVLEZYOblkMryoITQ1bfGck_jdq_hiCu5qtz1JEhTyYXpv3RxJ_8Bnp4Do_PKfMUbqxNaDbZr75sr83HTWlcsBcPYIVG3xXRAXcB4rRKB25NitdGBkg4zqcc9SiVqBgxT2FNWEjugs-tanNjcNODX_sradOQ-7RLlcTy7NRLqa3lUyNSBpow__X5DjJpGRQoym-9j3PRQGQGOQgNImuplYQ066n4W-TzradcaxLm0oCaSqlfZ9Ozn-9as5NHMdUlNYHpOb1aAi5Qxg0JtVvdSKAYiWpwmEzBAkTm3PWMRwQpXHMqGNgkpibwI3QcqY5IrPB1ZZ0xnZ-_bOHbpFLxgAMGGBRkIBVIqPmxCxqZz06TsQWGAF9cZ12c "/>
                            <endpoint key="iAppraisal"/>
                        </call>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't wrap `<property name="" ... />` inside `<call >` mediator. It should be before call endpoint like below:

```
<property name="Authorization" scope="transport" value="Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJK /.../ Z12c"/>
<call description="VB iAppraisal Endpoint">
    <endpoint key="iAppraisal"/>
</call>
```

Or optionally you can put that inside Endpoint definition.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!! I tired these but what I get is invalid token error what else should I do to sort this out

Comment: First check out your provided token. If he is valid, not expierd and so on..

Comment: I checked the token with postman and it's a valid one but when I tired to pass the token via api I get the invalid token error..